# How to train your model in deeppavlov (NER) Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, named-entity-recognition

First of all, sorry for any newbie mistakes that I've made. But I couldn't figure out and couldn't find a source specifically for [deeppavlov (NER)](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/ner.html) library. I'm trying to train ner_ontonotes_bert_mult as described [here](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/ner.html#train-and-use-the-model). I guess it can be trained from its checkpoint to make it recognize some specific patterns like;

```
"Round 23/22; 24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3"
```

as

```
[[['Round', '23/22', ';', '24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3']], [['B-PRODUCT', 'I-PRODUCT', 'B-QUANTITY']]]
```

My questions are (before I dig into details):

1. <s>Is it possible?</s>  And I realized I can't use samples like " Round 23/22; 24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3 ". I need them to be in full sentences.
2. Where can I find more info about it specifically related to deeppavlov's model(s)?
3. How can I train pre-trained deeppavlov model to recognize my custom patterns?

I don't even understand if it is possible but I've decided to give it go and prepared 3 `.txt` files as `"train.txt"`, `"test.txt"` and `"validation.txt"` as [described in deeppovlov web page](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/ner.html#training-data). And I put them under the folder `'~/.deeppavlov/downloads/ontonotes/ner_ontonotes_bert_mult'`. My dataset looks like this:

```
Round B-PRODUCT
23/22 I-PRODUCT
24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3 B-QUANTITY
Ring B-PRODUCT
HDFAA I-PRODUCT
12,7 x 10 B-QUANTITY
```

and so on... This is the code I am trying to train it:

```
import os
# Force tensorflow to use CPU instead of GPU.
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
from deeppavlov import configs, train_model
from deeppavlov.core.commands.utils import parse_config

config_dict = parse_config(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult)

print(config_dict['dataset_reader']['data_path'])

from deeppavlov import configs, train_model

ner_model = train_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [3] rhs shape= [37]
     [[{{node save/Assign_280}}]]
```

Full traceback:

```
2019-09-26 15:50:27.63 ERROR in 'deeppavlov.core.common.params'['params'] at line 110: Exception in <class 'deeppavlov.models.bert.bert_ner.BertNerModel'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/custom_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/custom_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/custom_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [3] rhs shape= [37]
     [[{{node save/Assign_280}}]]
```

## **UPDATE 2:**

And I realized I can't use samples like " Round 23/22; 24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3 ". I need them to be in full sentences.

## **UPDATE:**

It seems like this is happening due to my dataset. My custom dataset only has 3 tags (`B-PRODUCT`, `I-PRODUCT` and `B-QUANTITY`) but the pre-trained model has 37 of them. All available tags can be found [here](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/features/models/ner.html#multilingual-bert-zero-shot-transfer) under the sentence of `"The list of available tags and their descriptions are presented below."`. 18 main tags(with `B` and `I` 36 tags), and `O` tag (“O” means the absence of entity.)). **Total of all of the 37 tags needs to be present in the dataset.** I was able to pass that error by adding dummy sentences by tagging them all with the missing tags. This is a terrible workaround since I'm willingly disrupting my own data-set. I'm still looking for a 'logical' way to train...

PS: Now I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/custom_user/.PyCharm2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_9.py", line 13, in <module>
    ner_model = train_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult)
  File "/home/custom_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deeppavlov/__init__.py", line 31, in train_model
    train_evaluate_model_from_config(config, download=download, recursive=recursive)
  File "/home/custom_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deeppavlov/core/commands/train.py", line 121, in train_evaluate_model_from_config
    trainer.train(iterator)
  File "/home/custom_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deeppavlov/core/trainers/nn_trainer.py", line 294, in train
    self.train_on_batches(iterator)
  File "/home/custom_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deeppavlov/core/trainers/nn_trainer.py", line 234, in train_on_batches
    self._validate(iterator)
  File "/home/custom_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deeppavlov/core/trainers/nn_trainer.py", line 150, in _validate
    metrics = list(report['metrics'].items())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two problems here:
1. instead of `validation.txt` there should be a `valid.txt` file;
2. you are trying to retrain a model that was pretrained on a different dataset with a different set of tags, it's not necessary.

To train your model from scratch you can do something like:

```py
import json
from deeppavlov import configs, build_model, train_model

with configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult.open(encoding='utf8') as f:
    ner_config = json.load(f)

ner_config['dataset_reader']['data_path'] = '~/my_data_dir/'  # directory with train.txt, valid.txt and test.txt files
ner_config['metadata']['variables']['NER_PATH'] = '~/where_to_save_the_model/'
ner_config['metadata']['download'] = [ner_config['metadata']['download'][-1]]  # do not download the pretrained ontonotes model

ner_model = train_model(ner_config, download=True)
```

The other thing that could go wrong is tokenization: `"Round 23/22; 24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3"` will be split by the model to `['Round', '23', '/', '22', ';', '24', ',', '9', 'x', '12', ',', '2', 'x', '12', ',', '3']` and not `['Round', '23/22', ';', '24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3']`.

But you can tokenize your texts beforehand:

```py
ner_model([['Round', '23/22', ';', '24,9 x 12,2 x 12,3']])
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. My tokenization-by-hand is wrong. And again, you are right; I can train my own model. But I wanted to use a pre-trained model and extend its ability to tag words. That's why I am trying to retrain a pre-trained model.

Answer (score 1):

I tried deeppavlov training, and successfully trained the 'ner' model

I also got the same error at first while training, then I overcome by researching more about it

things to know before training -

-> you can find the 'ner_ontonotes_bert_multi.json' config file link in deeppavlov doc, which gives the dataset path, pretrained model path , dataset_reader and chain pipe to train

-> there is a pretrained model in the directory mentioned in the 'config'  ,by default it is inside 'C:/users/{user_name}/.deeppavlov/' is the root directory and pretrained models are gonna store in 'models' subdirectory

-> when you started training the already trained model is gonna be modified which means, training just try to improve the pre-trained model

so to train and build your own model (by scratch), simply delete the 'models' subdirectory  from the '.deeppavlov' path and execute the training